# Do I have to install mosh-server on my server to use Mosh?

Tags: mosh

I have installed `mosh` on my MacOS via brew. Everything went perfect.

After I tried to connect to my server, I got a message:

```
localhost:~ darkstaff$ mosh root@*.*.*.*
root@*.*.*.*'s password: 
bash: mosh-server: command not found
Connection to *.*.*.* closed.
/usr/local/bin/mosh: Did not find mosh server startup message. (Have you installed mosh on your server?)
```

Do I have to install Mosh on my server? If so, how could I install?

I am using `Debian`.

Comment: Yes you do. see the [faq](https://mosh.org/#faq). Look for a debian package called mosh.

Answer (score 3):

Yeah. The client has to talk to something on the remote end. It uses SSH for the initial connection, but the idea of mosh is that it uses its own protocol, so it needs its own server program too.

I'd suggest also using `screen` or `tmux` with mosh, since if the client dies (e.g. you reboot your laptop), there's no way to reconnect to the running mosh session on the server.

`apt-get install mosh screen`

Comment: May I know what is `screen` for in this case?

Comment: @AGamePlayer, it allows reattaching to the session if the client dies, like I said. Without it, anything you have running under mosh keeps running but is inaccessible if the client dies. (You don't need it if the network gets disconnected, just if the client process closes for any reason.) Also, you get multiple windows multiplexed in that one terminal.